# matplotlib: remove slider after clicking on button again

Tags: python, matplotlib, button, widget, slider

I want that the slider (f01) disappears by clicking on the button WR3(='WR2.2'). So that there is no overlay and the slider is new. I have no idea how to update or delete this complete slider. Here is my code:

```
from numpy import pi, sin
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import pylab
w0=1.7
lamb=0.4119
f0=lamb*1.0/(299.792458)
#lamb=f0*1.0/(299.792458)
d_in=80.0
R1=46.672
R2=686.468
foc=1/((1/R1)+(1/R2))
c=299792458000.0
zR=np.pi*w0**(2)/(c/(f0*1000000000.0))
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x_start=0.0
x_end=500.0
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(x_start,x_end+20.0, 20.0))
axis_color = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.35)
x = np.arange(x_start,x_end, 0.01)

w0_0 = 1.7
f0_0 = 727.82825
w1_0=w0*np.sqrt(1.0/(((d_in)/foc-1.0)**(2)+(zR/foc)**(2)))
d_in_0=80.0
d_out_0=foc+(d_in-foc)/(((d_in)/foc-1.0)**(2)+(zR/foc)**(2))

# function 1 and 2
def signal(w0,f0):
    return w0*np.sqrt(1.0+(x/(np.pi*w0**(2)/(c/(f0*1000000000.0))))**(2))
[line] = ax.plot(x, signal(w0_0, f0_0), linewidth=2, color='red')
WR3_button_ax = fig.add_axes([0.025, 0.7, 0.05, 0.05])
WR3_button = Button(WR3_button_ax, 'WR2.2:', color=axis_color, hovercolor='0.975')

# Define an axes area and draw a slider in it
w0_slider_ax  = fig.add_axes([0.25, 0.2, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg=axis_color)
w0_slider = Slider(w0_slider_ax, 'w0 [mm]', 0.1, 9.2, valinit=w0_0)

def WR3_button_on_clicked(mouse_event):
    f01_slider_ax = fig.add_axes([0.25, 0.25, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg=axis_color)
    f01_slider = Slider(f01_slider_ax, 'f0 [GHz]', 340.0, 500.0, valinit=d_in)
    w0_slider.set_val(1.5)
    f01_slider.set_val(340.0)
    def sliders_on_changed(val):
        line.set_ydata(signal(w0_slider.val, f01_slider.val))
        fig.canvas.draw_idle()
    f01_slider.on_changed(sliders_on_changed)

WR3_button.on_clicked(WR3_button_on_clicked)

plt.show()
```

I create this function, and the its about the slider f01.
Thank you

Comment: Do you mean `slider_ax.remove()`? The code is a bit chaotic, so it would also help if you explained in detail what you are trying to achieve in general.

Comment: Sorry for that. Exactly, this is what I need. If I plug this code right behind the 3rd line from below, the slider is created when clicked on the WR3 button and directly removed. I want to create the button by clicking first and then with another click to be deleted and created again, so that by another click on the button, the button is created new but the old one is deleted.

Comment: As said, I do have some problems understanding the logic here. As a general advise: Can you define all sliders and buttons you'll ever need outside of any function and set the axes of those you don't need invisible (`.set_visible(False)`). Inside your callback functions set the visibility as required. And avoid defining functions inside functions (this is in general possible but makes it just very hard to follow where things happen).