# matplotlib widget: create different sliders by clicking different buttons

Tags: matplotlib, button, widget, slider

I want to create a slider that appears by clicking a certain button. If I click another button I want this slider to disappear and instantly a new slider created at the same position.
For example:
I have 2 buttons: button1 and button2
If I click button 1, slider1 is created at xy=0.5,0.5 with a certain value range a until b.
If I now click button 2, slider1 disappears and slider2 is created at xy=0.5,0.5 with different value range c until b.

I have written a script, so I can create these different sliders, but I have the problem of the removing. If for example I click 2 times on button1, another slider1 comes on top of the first printed slider1. 
Can you help me?

Comment: I think I gave you [some clue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51674388/matplotlib-remove-slider-after-clicking-on-button-again#comment90313021_51674388) about how to accomplish that already. In how far is this not working?

Comment: I am sorry, but I did not understand your answer. Could you please write me an example?

Comment: Create all sliders at once. Turn those you don't need invisible. Inside your button callback set the visibility of the sliders as you wish (`ax_slider.set_visible(True)` or `False`).

Comment: Okay, now I understood. Yeah good idea, I tried this, but when I callback and set the visibility "True" for a certain slider, all other sliders are printed too, although I just set one certain slider to be visible. I think the problem is hiding in the definition: I defined the sliders all at the same position and set visibility False. When I now go for the callback, not only one slider is printed but all (they do overwrite each other). I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: Now this seems like a useful question. Why not show the code ([mcve]) that reproduces this problem, such that people can help fixing it?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here we go:
This code first defines 3 different sliders (f010,f015,f022) that are set invisible and 3 different buttons (WR10,WR15,WR22). Tje sliders are all at the same xy position. 
Then each button should call a specific slider, e.g. Button WR10 --> slider f010.
The problem is, that if one button is clicked, all 3 sliders are called and do overwrite each other.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from numpy import pi, sin
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

#Plot
axis_color = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.35)

#Define Sliders and set all invisible
f010_slider_ax = fig.add_axes([0.25, 0.25, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg=axis_color)
f010_slider = Slider(f010_slider_ax, 'f0_10 [GHz]', 750.0, 1100.0, valinit=750.0)
f010_slider_ax.set_visible(False)

f015_slider_ax = fig.add_axes([0.25, 0.25, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg=axis_color)
f015_slider = Slider(f015_slider_ax, 'f0_15 [GHz]', 500.0, 750.0, valinit=500.0)
f015_slider_ax.set_visible(False)

f022_slider_ax = fig.add_axes([0.25, 0.25, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg=axis_color)
f022_slider = Slider(f022_slider_ax, 'f0_22 [GHz]', 340.0, 500.0, valinit=340.0)
f022_slider_ax.set_visible(False)


#Define WR buttons
WR10_button_ax = fig.add_axes([0.025, 0.9, 0.05, 0.05])
WR10_button = Button(WR10_button_ax, 'WR1.0:', color=axis_color, hovercolor='0.975')

WR15_button_ax = fig.add_axes([0.025, 0.8, 0.05, 0.05])
WR15_button = Button(WR15_button_ax, 'WR1.5:', color=axis_color, hovercolor='0.975')

WR22_button_ax = fig.add_axes([0.025, 0.7, 0.05, 0.05])
WR22_button = Button(WR22_button_ax, 'WR2.2:', color=axis_color, hovercolor='0.975')


#Define Event on Buttons
def WR10_button_on_clicked(mouse_event): 
    f010_slider_ax.set_visible(True)    
WR10_button.on_clicked(WR10_button_on_clicked)

def WR15_button_on_clicked(mouse_event):
    f015_slider_ax.set_visible(True)
WR15_button.on_clicked(WR15_button_on_clicked)

def WR22_button_on_clicked(mouse_event):
    f022_slider_ax.set_visible(True)
WR22_button.on_clicked(WR22_button_on_clicked)


plt.show()
```